# Using group_concat to remove duplicates with linking tables

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, group-concat

I am building a library system using MySQL. The database includes tables for the music, composer and arranger. These are linked through linking tables. One piece of music might have multiple composers and/or arrangers. I have a basic query working properly, which shows the title, composer and arranger, but if there are multiple composers or arrangers, they appear on separate lines in the table. I'm trying to use GROUP_CONCAT to combine those rows, with a ; separator (so that each title has only one line in the results, but I'm having trouble incorporating the linking tables into the logic.

Here are samples of my tables:

Music table

| music_id | music_title | music_drawer | music_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 650 East | 37 | 3 |

Composer table

| composer_id | composer_fullname |
| --- | --- |
| 319 | Oldham, Wayne |
| 167 | Hale, Ja |

musiccomposerlink table

| music_composer_id | music_id | composer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 319 |
| 2 | 5 | 167 |

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT
    mus.music_title AS title,
    mus.music_id,
    IFNULL(mus.music_drawer, '') AS drawer,
    IFNULL(mus.music_number, '') AS num,
    IFNULL(com.composer_fullname, '') AS composer

FROM
    music AS mus
    LEFT JOIN musiccomposerlink AS mcl ON mus.music_id = mcl.music_id
    LEFT JOIN composers AS com ON mcl.composer_id = com.composer_id
    
WHERE
    mus.music_title LIKE '%650%'
ORDER BY
    title,
    composer
```

This produces the following table of results:

Search Results

| Title | music_id | drawer | num | composer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 650 East | 5 | 37 | 3 | Hale, Ja |
| 650 East | 5 | 37 | 3 | Oldham, Wayne |

What I'd like to accomplish with the GROUP_CONCAT is output that looks like:

Search Results

| Title | music_id | drawer | num | composer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 650 East | 5 | 37 | 3 | Hale, Ja; Oldham, Wayne |

Eventually, I'd like to add an additional column in the results for arrangers. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) expression like this, in queries with GROUP BY.

```sql
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT com.composer ORDER BY com.composer SEPARATOR '; ') composers
```

In your query replace your existing `ORDER BY` clause with this:

```sql
GROUP BY mus.music_title, 
         mus.music_id,
         IFNULL(mus.music_drawer, ''),
         IFNULL(mus.music_number, '')
ORDER BY mus.music_title
```

and you'll have the result you want.

Or, if you want to preserve the order of composers in your `musiccomposerlink` table, use this.

```sql
GROUP_CONCAT(com.composer ORDER BY mcl.music_composer_id SEPARATOR '; ') composers
```

Most librarians insist upon preserving the order of the names of creators of the works they catalog.